# filtered Array Using two Predicates

Tags: iphone, ios, nsarray, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I was wondering if there is a way to refine a Array using two filteredArrayUsingPredicates, currently I am refining it using one of the values in the array but there are several other values... I would like to know how to do it so i can refine by two of the varaibales.

currently I am doing this

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K like %@",@"ISCHARGER",@"T"]; // I have another 
NSArray *filteredArray = [parsedDataArrayOfDictionaries filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you mean you want some compound predicates like `NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(lastName like[cd] %@) AND (birthday > %@)", lastNameSearchString, birthdaySearchDate];`? (which is in Predicate Programming Guide)

Comment: yes that is what I mean... I totally should have checked out the documents but didn't even think... sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do the following:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userID == %d AND messageID == %d", currentUser, currentMessage];
```

Hope this helps,

Tom